# Going from regex to word vba (.Find)

Tags: regex, vba, ms-word

I have this regex

```
<#([^\s]+).*?>\s?<a href=""(.*?)"".*?>(.*?)</a>(\s?\((Pending|Prepared)\))?
```

And i really need it in a vba version for words .find method (don't need the matching-groups), here is what i have so far

```
\<\#*\>*\<a href=*\>*\<\/a\>
```

But i cant get the last part to work, here I'm talking about

```
(\s?\((Pending|Prepared)\))?
```

I really hope someone can help me, as regex in this case is not an option (Although i know i can use regex in VBA!)

Cheers

Comment: Curious to know why regex is not an option for you?  Also, might be worth mentioning that regex is not well-suited for parsing HTML/XML/etc., you may be better using a proper DOM parser...

Comment: To answer your second question first:
I know, but i am migrating process cards from an xml/html solution to word documents, and to this i am using a parser. But i had some tables all written in the same xml tag, but html formated (bold, italic & links) so im using regex on this single xml tag to make bold, italic and links.. and the "<#([^\s]+).*?>" part is some information about an icon for the individual link.. all this is working now. But i need the Pending/Prepared text after the link.

First question: I already wrote a large amount of this using .Find, and i would really hate rewriting :(

Comment: Can you give sample data that would be matched by this regex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see an OR `|` in the documentation [(Wildcard character reference)](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/help/add-power-to-word-searches-with-regular-expressions-HA001087305.aspx) or the examples [(Putting regular expressions to work in Word)](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/support/putting-regular-expressions-to-work-in-word-HA001087304.aspx?CTT=5&origin=HA001087305), so instead I suggest splitting it into two separate searches. The Word MVPs site has a [good reference](http://word.mvps.org/FAQs/General/UsingWildcards.htm) on the Word Regex as well if you want more information.

`[^\s]` can be written in the Word style regex as `[! ]` (note the space), `+` becomes `@`. It appears that neither the `{n,}` nor `{n,m}` syntax of VBA support an n value of 0, making `?` and `*` hard to implement in Word.  One option that the MS guys seem to use is `*`, which in Word is "Any string of characters". By my testing, `*` is lazy, meaning the pattern `\<#*\>` run against the string `<#sometag> asdfsadfasdf >` will only match `<#sometag>`. In addition, it can match 0 characters, for example `\<\#*\>` will match `<#>`.

So assuming that the first part is working as you expect, you could try the following two regex:

`\<\#*\>*\<a href=*\>*\<\/a\>*\(Pending\)`

and

`\<\#*\>*\<a href=*\>*\<\/a\>*\(Prepared\)`

The trouble here is that the * will match up until it hits the P of Pending or Prepared, so there could be other text in between, but it's the only way I can see of matching an optional space.  If you can guaruntee that the space will or will not be there, that would go a long way towards making the regex safer.

Give that a try and see if it works for you!

Comment: Thank you kind sir!
I will test it the next time i reach my work computer, and let you know if it works.. Further more i will give an example of the data matched.. 
And ofc accept your answer if it works.